# Segmentation Fault C++ | Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I wrote this code to find optimal warping path of Dynamic time warping , it returns a struct .

```
static inline double min (double x, double y,double z )
{
    if(x < y && x < z)
    return x;
    else if(y < x && y < z)
    return y;
    else if(z < x && z < y)
    return z;
}

struct backtracking_result
{
   vector<int> i;
   vector<int> j;
};

backtracking_result backtracking(vector<vector<double> > mGamma)
{
    backtracking_result br;
    cout<<"test"<<mGamma.size()<<endl;
    int i=mGamma.size();
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
    int j=mGamma.at(0).size();
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
    cout<<i<<j<<endl;   
    do
    {
         cout<<"test"<<endl;
         if(i == 1)
            j=j-1;
         else if(j == 1)
            i=i-1;
         else
         {
            if(mGamma[i-1][j] == min(mGamma[i-1][j],mGamma[i][j-1],mGamma[i-1][j-1]))
             i=i-1;
            else if(mGamma[i][j-1] == min(mGamma[i-1][j],mGamma[i][j-1],mGamma[i-1][j-1]))
                 j=j-1;
            else
            {
                i=i-1;
                j=j-1;
            }
         }
    br.i.push_back(i);
    br.j.push_back(j);
  }while((i > 1)&&(j > 1));

  return br;
}
```

When i call this function , get this error from gdb debugger

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000041eafb in VectorDTW::backtracking(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >) ()
```

Where is the error ?

Stacktrace :

```
#0  0x000000000041eb17 in VectorDTW::backtracking(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >) ()
#1  0x0000000000420195 in VectorDTW::fastdynamic(std::vector<DollarRecognizer::Point2D, std::allocator<DollarRecognizer::Point2D> >&, std::vector<DollarRecognizer::Point2D, std::allocator<DollarRecognizer::Point2D> >&) ()
#2  0x000000000041d18b in main ()
```

The answers helped me figure out the problem , I added these two lines after calculating i & j at from the matrix ,

```
i=i-1;
j=j-1;
```

Now the program doesn't try to access the last element . Thanks . 
But i still cannot understand the reason for down-votes .

Comment: What line do you get the crash at?

Comment: Does the code even compile? min takes 3 arguments? or I am wrong?

Comment: It compiles , i have edited the question to include  the code of min .

Comment: do you know there is a standard min function?

Comment: haha... just read that you already run from gdb... what does your stack trace say?

Comment: @Aniket Thanks , i didn't notice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `j` is the size of the internal `vector<double>`, `mGamma[i-1][j]` does not exist. You have the typical off-by-one error.

Comment: why does mGamma[i-1][j] not exist ? mGamma is a mxm matrix and in the while loop i have already specified that i>1 && j>1

Comment: @rajat If your `vector<>` size is `j`, elements range from `0` to `j-1`.

Comment: because vector is 0 index, so if the vector's size is N, the vector's indexes go from 0 to N-1. You cannot access [N] which is beyond vector's limits

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do a better checking `mGamma.size()` and `mGamma.at(0).size()` because if *mGamma*'s size is 0, you access a position *at(0)* which does not exist.
If `mGamma.size()` is not 0, but the `at(0).size()` is 0, you will go in the else part of your code accessing a vector with a negative index causing a segfault.

Comment: It's a standard , m x m matrix . i can see both the values . mGamma.size() and mGamma.at(0).size();

Comment: yes , i am sure . And if it's 0 i already have a condition to go into the loop when i>1 & j>1 .

Comment: I think the error is the one pointed from @Gorpik's  answer. However you are not checking if it's 0 on the first run. The do {} while(condition) loop runs the code once and then check the condition.